# Como recibir los datos enviados mediante XHttpRequest por POST en Wordpress [ Wordpress - $_POST - XHttpRequest ]

Tags: wordpress, post, wordpress-plugin, xmlhttprequest

Estoy mandando un id a través de XHttpRequest en Wordpress pero a la hora de recibir el valor mediante $_POST['id'] me indica que es null.
Por lo visto no es la forma corretca que admite para realizar la petición en Wordpress, si alguien sabe como poder hacerla correctamente y recibir los datos mediante POST utilizando XHttpRequest se lo agradezco.
Saludos !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mediante POST no he podido conseguirlo con XHttpRequest pero con el método GET no me ha dado ningún problema.
Así que usaré $_GET y listo.
Saludos !